# How can I use "Product purchased" as a secondary dimension in Geo?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to map out the locations of where customers are based on Product ID. So essentially a map of all people that purchased X product. I'm able to make geographic reports based on page visited as the secondary dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Enhanced Ecommerce enabled and implemented, you can create a custom segment of users, who have purchased product X. E.g:

[image]